# angularjs send nested object to API

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing angular with web API application. I am trying receive object with array from angular. Unfortunately I am receiving `null` in the array.

```
this.updateprocesswithtemplates = function () {
    var sub = {
        projectId: "50",
        code: "app",
        templates: {
            title: "templatetiltle",
            version: "templateversion",
            visible: "templatevisible",
            templatefileid: "31",
            displayorder: "1"
        }
    };
    var responseservice = $http.put('/api/processes/81/', sub).success(function (response) {});
    return responseservice;
}
```

In  web API i have below class

```
  public class updatercvparams
        {
           public string projectId{ get; set; }
           public int code { get; set; }
           public templates[] templates { get; set; }
        }
 public class templates
        {
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string version { get; set; }
            public int displayorder { get; set; }
            public string visibility { get; set; }
            public int templatefileid { get; set; }
        }
```

When I send above request object I will receive `null` in templates.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, updatercvparams obj)
```

May I know, Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have defined `templates` as an array, you need to send an array not a object.

```
var sub = {
    projectId: "50",
    code: "app",
    templates: [{
        ....
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your entity(class) in web api, field name should be same in javascript object. While you sending list of data like array, use square bracts('[]').

```js
this.updateprocesswithtemplates = function() {
  var sub = {
    projectId: "50",
    code: "app",
    templates: [{
      title: "templatetiltle",
      version: "templateversion",
      visibility: "templatevisible",
      templatefileid: "31",
      displayorder: "1"
    }]
  };
  var responseservice = $http.put('/api/processes/81/', JSON.stringify(sub))
    .success(function(response) {});
  return responseservice;
}
```